# Xdocument.Load(XMLReader.Read()) Is giving me erros

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq

I am trying to load a document see the code below

```
 try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                XmlReader responseReader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream());

                XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(responseReader.Read());
```

The above line is telling me xdocument.Load has some invalid arguments.

```
                //XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

This line is not loading anything Docs is empty

```
               XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(responseReader);
```

This line is not giving any overload errors but returning nothing.

```
List<string> books = docs.Descendants("Test")....."Remaining QQuery"
```

Comment: can you post the actual error message?

Comment: Cannot Convert from Bool To String                                          Best Overloaded method match for 'system.xml.linq.xdocument.Load(string') has some invalid arguments

Comment: There's no need to create an XmlReader; you should be able to do: XDocument docs = 
    XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())); Is docs still empty after that (check docs.Nodes.Count)? If it is, it's time to look in the response itself.

Comment: @SmilingLily No problem - I've given you some more troubleshooting tips below if you run into any problems with the response itself. It's amazing how many programming issues can be solved with one line of code, though, isn't it!

Comment: Thank you Dash. It took me more than 3 hrs to resolve this :(

Comment: @SmilingLily Next time it wont take you any time at all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you almost had it without the XmlReader; you can't load the response straight into the XDocument, but, most of the time you can do:

```
XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()));
```

Then check docs.Nodes.Count.

If docs is still empty, it's time to look at the response itself. Look at the response.ContentType - what is it?

Assuming the response isn't too large, look at it! You can do:

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseSteam());
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

You can dump that string anywhere. Alternatively, if it is very big, you can save the response to disk, using either a FileStream with your Response, or, more simply `WebClient.DownloadFile(url, path_to_save)`

Either should be good enough to get you one step closer.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(responseReader.Read());
```

to

```
XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(responseReader);
```

The method for XDocument will accept an XmlReader which is what responseReader is, however you are calling the .Read() method on which only returns a boolean which is why you are getting that error.

Comment: I did tried that before(Mentioned it in the OP) but it is not loading anything for docs. It is coming Empty.